# How to define Google BigQuery constraints?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to define constraints on BigQuery tables. How can I do this? Are constraints enforced in BigQuery?

Comment: Please edit your question to show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You can also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I am not sure how to be more specific. I want to define constraints on BigQuery tables and I do not know how. I do not see any sign of constraints in the documentation but I have a hard time believing that constraints are not supported at all in BigQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I interpret the question in the context of [SQL constraints](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_constraints.asp). The only constraint that BigQuery supports is `NOT NULL` one, and it is modeled by setting `REQUIRED` field mode on table schema (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables)